# A MongoDB update query to update array values to their lowercase value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo collection of states, where each state contains an array of cities:

```
{
   "_id":"636d1137cf1e57408486f795",
   "state":"new york",
   "cities":[
      {
         "cityid":"62bd8fa5396ba8aef4ad1041",
         "name":"Yonkers"
      },
      {
         "cityid":"62bd8fa5396ba8aef4ad1043",
         "name":"Syracuse"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need an update query that will lowercase every `cities.name` in the collection.
I can do an update with a literal value e.g.

```
db.states.updateMany(
   {},
   { $set: { "cities.$[].name" : "some_value" } }
)
```

... ,  but I need the value to be based on the existing value. The closest I can get is something like this (but that doesn't work -- `FieldPath field names may not start with '$'`)

```
db.states.updateMany(
   {},
   { $set: { "cities.$[].name" : { $toLower:  "cities.$[].name"} } }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain up `$map` and `$mergeObjects` to perform the update. Put it in an aggregation pipeline in update.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      cities: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$cities",
          "as": "c",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$c",
              {
                "name": {
                  "$toLower": "$$c.name"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OXxNVaM5FdB)